# Can we have two evn.rb files in cucumber framework for Watir-Webdriver and REST API project Testing

Tags: ruby, rest, cucumber, watir-webdriver, httparty

Presently i have two individual projects for Rest API and Watir-webdriver with cucumber , so i planned to move them into one project , so is it possible to make it as one project

I would like to keep My Rest API framework [ Cucumber + Httparty + Json ] and Watir-webdriver framework [ Cucumber + Watir-webdriver ] in one project, 
Is it possible can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have service/browser tests within the same project, actually, it's common given a lot can be reused between both ui and service test layers... I don't think it's possible to have 2 env.rb files and to be honest there is no reason why you would want to... but I get why you thought about it...

There are a LOT of ways you can manage your service/ui frameworks within a single repo and it's entirely up to you the path you follow... Below is one of many ways you can accomplish this:

Within both of your frameworks, you probably have unique setup in you env.rb... abstract those unique dependencies into a module in the same level as env.rb, for example:

```
service.rb
browser.rb
```

Within each module add the steps you require for your ui/service tests:

```
module ServiceHelper/BrowserHelper      
  def service_setup/browser_setup
  end
end
```

now in your env.rb file, based in some ENV variable config you call the setup for your browser or service test:

```
require 'service'
require 'browser'

include 'BrowserHelper'
include 'ServiceHelper'

if ENV['driver'] = 'service'
  service_setup
elsif ENV['driver'] = 'browser'
  browser_setup
else
  ...
end
```

In the end, you will probably find that your UI tests will reuse a lot of stuff from you service test suite, for example, data setup can be done via services to assist your UI tests... when you get to that conclusion, you will no longer need to have a clause and load one or the other... but the abstracting setup service/browser into modules, outside of env.rb is still a good practice, you then keep env.rb clean, and helps manage your different setup for different purposes...

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me suggestion.  solution is very good , i am going to implement it and let you know and please help me if i get stuck anywhere :-)

Comment: user3087106 : hi , 
how can i handle the hooks for Service / Browser . can you please tell me

Comment: again there are several ways of doing that... a easy way is by tagging your service/browser features... then you exclude those features if the hook is not meant for them... for example:

Service/Browser features have tag @service/@browser... Then in your hook for service, run it for service and exclude it for browser After('@service', '~@browser') do ....

Comment: user3087106 : Thanks a lot for showing me the path, i have done it as per your idea , but hooks is created some issues when i tried to execute the service.rb . so i have created a check in hook.rb page like                             if EVN['driver'] == 'service'
 before do
 end
 
 at_exit do
 end
elsif
 execute the service suite
end

Then it is working as per requirement ,anyway 
Thanks again for helping me out :-)

Comment: glad I could assist =)